# Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I read in other topics, but I can't quite figure this out. I have an EJB module that uses log4j. I want to package that EJB into a JAR file and put in the WEB-INF/lib path of a web project. The web project has a servlet that executes a function from the EJB, and that's it. But seems that the appender doesn't work, for the file is created but not written.

I read that a deployment descriptor for JBoss, so I created one based on one of the previous posts. But i get a "Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment" error.

> 12:04:44,905 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SampleWeb.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SampleWeb.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "SampleWeb.war"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
>   Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Sub deployment SampleEJB.jar in jboss-structure.xml was not found. Available sub deployments: 
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.subDeploymentNotFound(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:233) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       ... 5 more

Here's the jboss-deployment-structure.xml I created. Because the web project only uses the EJB jar file I created I assumed that the deployment tag is not used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<sub-deployment name="SampleEJB.jar">
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        <module name="org.log4j"/>  
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    </exclusions>
</sub-deployment>
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like eclipse issue, may happen when **dependant project of an ear not built properly**.

In my case I was getting the same error with reason that ear was unable to find one included dependency jar.
Just check that dependent project and check it's target directory where maven creates jar after building the project. It would be empty if maven does not build that project properly. 
**Build that dependent project separately** by "mvn install" and then try deploying ear on your server. 
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Sub deployment SampleEJB.jar in jboss-structure.xml **was not found.**

It seems `SampleEJB.jar` is not deployed yet. Create [deployment structure file](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide?_sscc=t) to deploy components in order.

Comment: Weird. I put it in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the web application. Should it be somewhere else? Or shall I put it with the whole path like "WEB-INF/lib/SampleEJB.jar"?

Comment: Shoulnd't it be outside and WAR + JAR be created as EAR?

Comment: As far as I read, the descriptor serves for EAR and WAR equally. I'm deploying a web application (WAR), and this is the only .jar file in the web application so I thought it was ok like that.

Comment: If it just WAR and JAR is in lib, I don't think you need any deployment structure file. In general if it EJB developed by you shouldn't it be treated as different module and packaged your entire APP as EAR instead of WAR?

Comment: Yes, but if the EJB it's a localbean, and I need some client to execute it's function so I'm using the web project. As I mentioned, I'm using the jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml because, it's not using the appender as I established in the properties of log4j inside the EJB.

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that the deployment of the "example.ear/SampleWeb.war" file has failed during the "STRUCTURE" phase, due to an exception caused by insufficient disk space. The deployment process could not complete successfully because there was no more space left on the device.

To resolve this issue, you will need to free up some disk space on the device where you are trying to deploy the application.Additionally, check the amount of space used by the server.log files and try to get rid of older log files.

To check the disk space use this command `df -h`